# Best approach for cancel an awaitable method before navigation?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, cancellation

I am working in Xamarin app, but I think my question is more focused in **.NET framework** and **C#**.

For example I navigate to **PageOne**, and in constructor is called the asynchronous method **InitializePageOneData()**...

```
public PageOne()
{
    await InitializePageOneData()
}
```

But just in this moment, while it is waiting for the method execution, I navigate to a second page (**PageTwo**), which has another asynchronous operations, but I see that the InitializePageOneData() method does not stops his execution.

My goal is to stop this asynchronous operation before doing the navigation to another page. What is your recommendation?

Note: in the asynchronous operation, I am using `TaskCompletionSource`:

```
    private Task<Response> ProcessRequest(Request request)
    {
        tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<Response>();

        eventHandler = (s, e) =>
        {
            try
            {
                _client.ProcessRequestsCompleted -= eventHandler;

                tsc.TrySetResult(e.Result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _client.ProcessRequestsCompleted -= eventHandler;
                tsc.TrySetException(ex);
            }
        };

        _client.ProcessRequestsCompleted += eventHandler;
        _client.ProcessRequestsAsync(request);

        return tsc.Task;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

> My goal is to stop this asynchronous operation before doing the
>   navigation to another page. What is your recommendation?

Pass down a [`CancellationToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx) to your async method, and monitor on that token. If the user wants to navigate away to page two, use the [`CancellationTokenSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource(v=vs.110).aspx) to cancel that operation.

An example would be:

```
private CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
public async Task LoadPageOneAsync()
{
    try
    {
        await InitializePageOneDataAsync(cts.Token)
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException e)
    {
        // Handle if needed.
    }
}

public async Task InitializePageOneDataAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    foreach (var something in collection)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        // Do other stuff
    }   
}
```

When you want to cancel, invoke `cts.Cancel()` from `PageTwo`:

```
public async Task LoadPageTwoAsync()
{
    cts.Cancel();
    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    await LoadSecondPageAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but how do I do the task cancellation?

Comment: in this case, call cts.Cancel()

Comment: @Fran_gg7 You're right, I forgot to mention that. Edited my answer.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, this is not working for me...maybe is because I am using TaskCompletionSource?

I update my question with my TaskCompletionSource implementation.

Comment: @Frann Where? I don't see

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov at the end of my question (1st message) :)

Comment: @Frann The way your async method is implemented you can only cancel at the beginning of the method.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I don't understand what do you mean

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84445/discussion-between-fran-gg7-and-yuval-itzchakov).